# Maximum sum of difference minimum and maximum elements of all contiguous subarrays

Tags: c++, c++14

**Degree of Freedom**

You are given an integer array A of size N.
You can divide this array A into any number of contiguous subarrays (possibly zero). The degree of freedom for a subarray is the absolute difference between the maximum and minimum element in a subarray.

**Task**:
Print the maximum sum of the degree of freedom of all subarrays that can be achieved by dividing A into some possible arrangement of contiguous subarrays

**Note**

•A subarray of an array is a sequence obtained by removing zero or more elements from either both the front and back of the array. The subarrays of array [1,5,2] are ([1], [1,5] [1,5,2], [5], [5,2],[2]] and [1,2] cannot be called a subarray of [1,5,2] because it cannot be obtained by removing elements from front or back of [1,5,2]
•Contiguous subarray means that all the subarrays should have consecutive indexes. An array [1,2,3] can be divided into contiguous subarray as [1,2,3]or [1,2],[3] or [1][2,3]

**Example**

**Assumptions**
N=5
A = [1,2,1,0,5]

Approach

Optimally we can divide A into three consecutive subarrays [1,2], [1] and [0,5]. The degree of freedoms of the subarrays is O and 5 respectively.
Thus the maximum sum of the degree of freedom of all subarrays is 6.

A Represents an integer array denoting elements of array A

Test Cases:
N=4; A=[1,4,2,3]; **Output**=4
N=5; A=[1,2,3,2,1]; **Output**=3

I have written the below code and I'm getting 8 as output but it should be 6.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
using namespace std; 
int degree(int *arr, int k, int n) {
   
    int res = 0;
   

    for (int i = 0; i <= (n - k); i++) {
        int min = INT_MAX;
        int max = INT_MIN;
       
        for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++) {
            min = std::min(min, arr[j]);
            max = std::max(max, arr[j]);
            
            cout<<min<<" "<<max<<endl;
        }
        res += abs(min - max);
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    return res;
}
int main() {
    
    int arr2[] = {1,2,1,0,5};
    int k2 = 2;
    cout<<degree(arr2, k2, sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]))<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this : if res is lesser than the current element, add to res otherwise no

Comment: @user1587368 it'll not work for the N=4; A=[1,4,2,3]; Output=4. You can suggest another apporoch for the question

Comment: This code doesn't do anything resembling the solution to the stated problem. All it does is add up differences between adjacent pairs of elements: `abs(1-2) + abs(2-1) + abs(1-0) + abs(0-5) == 8`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you suggest a solution for the problem

Comment: I can, but I won't do your homework for you. The term for further research is "dynamic programming".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not a student. I have tried dp also but I wasn't able to solve the problem

Comment: @BHARATSONI: How are you not a student? This assignment is a typical exercise given in a course; it is not an assignment given in a work setting. It might be a challenge problem in an online judge service, but that is still a learning scenario.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Dynamic programming is not needed. Wherever there is a sequence of ascending values or a sequence of descending values, it can be harvested to contribute to the sum by taking the sequence as a subarray. Splitting it further will not help as the sum of “degrees of freedom” of the subarrays will not exceed the “degree of freedom” of the sequence. An issue would be which subarray to put each local extremum in, as it can only go in one but would help both. It should go in the one in which its neighbor is farther, as it will do the most good in that one.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Consider `[2, 5, 1, 6]`. If I understand your algorithm, it would look at an ascending run `[2, 5]` and a descending run `[5, 1]` and conclude that `5` is best to go with `1`, and `2` should be on its own. Whereas the optimal partition is `[2,5][1,6]`. I don't believe any greedy algorithm looking only at immediate surroundings can arrive at an optimal solution for this problem: I believe it is possible to construct an arbitrarily long example where tweaking the last element affects the choice for the first element.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think it is true that monotonous runs longer than 4 elements can be simplified by removing middle elements (all but the smallest, next smallest, largest and next largest), and peaks and troughs consisting of 3 or more equal elements can be simplified by removing all but 2 (must keep pairs: `[1,5,1]` and `[1,5,5,1]` have different optimums). I believe this is the best you can do with local optimization, before using dynamic programming or similar to examine the input as a whole.

Comment: I suggest adding the same number of abs (min-max) only once: 1,1,1,5 => 6 and not 8 because 1 is repeated three times.